# sending span text to another page with JS and php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a dynamically changing span on a page displaying the number of votes a project has received. On another (target) page i have a list of projects. i want to be able to display that vote count there. i know how to grab the text from the span on the page. 
it would be something like this.

```
<span id="count1"></span>

var prj1c = $("#count1").text;
```

in know that on the other page i end up using

```
<?php echo $prj1c(this being after i assign the prj1c var to php somewhere) ?>
```

i also know i could create a php include page and call it on the target page, though i would like not to create a separate page for each of these instances.
so to sum up: how do i change a JS var to php and call it from another page- remember the text in the span changes (when users vote up or down)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, use `.text()` instead of `.text`

```
var prj1c = $("#count1").text(); //instead of  var prj1c = $("#count1").text;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "yourpage.php",
    data: {count :prj1c},
    success: function(response) {
         alert("Response "+response);
    }

 });
```

in yourpage.php add this `<?php echo $_POST['count']; ?>`

**Update:**

```
 $(function(){

     $("#count1").click(function(){
           window.location='page2.php?count='+$(this).text();
      });

});
```

**in page2.php:**

```
  <ul>
  <li id="projectName">
  <img><span>vote count goes HERE: <?php echo $_GET['count']; ?></span>
  </li></ul>
```

Comment: since i ran into problems implementing, i opened another post with more focused question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362709/sending-span-text-to-another-page-with-ajax-and-php

Answer (score 0):

You can try with jQuery Ajax request. When user vote up/down you can make an ajax call to the target page.

Eg.

```
var prj1c = $("#count1").text();

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "targetPage.php",
        data: "count="+prj1c,
        success: function(response) {
             alert("Response "+response);
          }

 });
```

Get the `prj1c` value in targetPage.php

```
 $prj1c = $_REQUEST['count'];
 // Follow appropriate steps later in targetPage.php
```

Comment: trying to make it work. no luck yet- is `$prj1c = $_REQUEST['count'];` in a php tag or in a <script>?, what are the following appropriate steps ? sorry- im a beginner

Comment: @user3108832 Sorry I was away from my PC. `$prj1c = $_REQUEST['count'];` in PHP tag. Appropriate steps I meant what need to be followed once you've span text got from the previous page.