# sending span text to another page with ajax and php

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

Have a a voting button that displays vote count in a span. id like to send the vote count to another page that has a list with project names and, hopefully, the vote count displayed there. trying this with`POST` method. trying this on wamp and getting error:

Notice: Undefined index: count in F:\wamp\www\myphphtester\page2.php on line 17
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0002  363312  {main}( )   ..\page2.php:0

what am i missing here for it to work?

Page1.php:

```
<div id="voteBtn">vote</div><span id="count1">Text(number) to be sent</span>

<script> var prj1c = $("#count1").text(); 
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "page2.php",
data: {count :prj1c},
success: function(response) {
     alert("Response "+response);
}  }); </script>
```

page2.php:

```
<ul>
<li id="projectName">
<img><span>vote count goes HERE: <?php echo $_POST['count']; ?></span>
</li></ul>
```

*this question continues from a previous post (that taught me a lot) at [sending span text to another page with JS and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361482/sending-span-text-to-another-page-with-js-and-php)

Comment: edited to show the error

Comment: You need to check the network tab in your browser's dev tools to check what gets sent and where.

Comment: Do you want to go to `page2.php` after the vote button is clicked?

Comment: @user007 not necessarily. i just want the specific vote count displayed there as well.

Comment: Then you need to either use sessions to keep track of the current vote count or update it into the database (if you are using one) whenever the vote count changes and use an ajax function on `page2.php` to keep checking if vote count has increased.